# Checking if point inside a cone - values and as a result plot (with matplotlib) inaccurate

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, 3d

I am receiving a stream of 3D points with `x`, `y` and `z` ranging from `0` to `65534`. Every `t` milliseconds I take a sample of points and check if the points lie outside an automatically defined cone. Here are the steps I use in my algorithm:

1. The first point is used to define the **tip of a right circular cone** (I'll use the `x_tip`, `y_tip` and `z_tip` coordinates to mark). The cone's height **h** is equal to `z_tip`
2. Using `x_tip` and `y_tip` of the tip I calculate the tip's projection on the plane at `z = 0`
3. Given an angle `a` I calculate the cone's radius `r` using the Pythagorean theorem:

   ```
   cos_angle = cos(a)
   if cos_angle != 0:
     hypotenuse = h / cos_angle
     sin_angle = sin(a)
     if sin_angle != 0:
       r = hypotenuse * sin_angle
   ```
4. After calculating the height and the radius I can apply a two-step test to determine whether the given point (beside the tip) is outside the cone (note that both points inside and lying on the surface of the cone are marked as *valid* that is part of the cone):

   - Point above cone - all points have `z` between `0` and `65534` with the same range also applying to the height of the cone. So checking whether a point lies below the cone is pointless (and impossible :)). Doing this check is a simple one-dimensional check that is check whether `z_point > z_tip` (if `true` then no further checking is necessary since the point is clearly above the cone). This test is in fact done as a prerequirement step for a point to land in the sample set. So all points that are being checked are at or below the level of `z_zip`
   - Point inside, lying on the circumference or outside the slice of the cone at the height of the point - this test is two-dimensional and here I use Euclidean distance (note that I have mapped the 0..65534 range to 0..1 because I'm printing this stuff in my terminal and floating point numbers are easier to compare visually (omho)):

     ```
     def pointInsideOrOnCircle(x, y, z):
       if r == 0:
         return False

       # Map the point that we need to validate to 0..1
       x = x/65534.
       y = y/65534.
       z = z/65534.

       # Map the first from the samples points (tip of cone) to 0..1
       x_tip = points[0, 0]/65534.
       y_tip = points[0, 1]/65534.

       # Map cone's radius and height
       h = h/65534.
       r = r/65534.

       # Calculate Euclidean distance from point to center of slice
       d = sqrt((x_tip - x)**2 + (y_tip - y)**2)

       # Calculate the radius of the cone's slice
       r_slice = (r*z)/h

       return d <= r_slice # If true, point lies inside or on surface of cone
     ```

I was thinking that this works but then I decided to plot it...The result looks rather strange:

**Example:**

For the sample

```
[
    [65534,62471,54690],
    [65534,59646,52585],
    [65534,56317,50283],
    [65240,52776,47825],
    [64508,49397,45249],
    [63357,46581,42549],
    [61838,44648,39719],
    [60011,43742,36772],
    [57902,43845,33730],
    [55473,44884,30622],
    [52618,46840,27472],
    [49215,49783,24311],
    [45291,53734,21167],
    [41294,58283,18073],
    [37942,62512,15059],
    [35498,65534,12158],
    [33748,65534,9399],
    [32488,65534,6808],
    [31445,65534,4405],
    [30533,65534,2205]
]
```

I get

[image]

**Example:**

For the sample

```
[
    [39130,65534,50773],
    [39387,65534,47926],
    [39700,65534,44867],
    [39991,65534,41689],
    [40185,65534,38404],
    [40213,65534,35034],
    [40023,65534,31614],
    [39583,65534,28187],
    [37913,65534,21521],
    [36686,65534,18402],
    [35219,65534,15506],
    [33574,65534,12883],
    [31892,65534,10570],
    [30378,65534,8592],
    [28339,65534,5679],
    [27757,65534,4740],
    [27361,65534,4138],
    [27094,65534,3859],
    [26824,65534,4017],
    [26790,65534,5566]
]
```

I get

[image]

Valid points are marked as **green** circles while invalid ones - as **red** circles. As you can see things don't add up - I have some of the points marked as valid even though these lie outside the cone and others that lie inside the cone but are marked as invalid. I have no idea where my mistake is - is it the algorithm, is it some rounding issue, is it the plot itself...

The full code below has some of the variables named a little bit different but it should be easy to follow up on these from the description above). The arrows are extra visualization for me to be able to see a couple of things easily (for example the red arrow points at the cone's tip, the blue one - at the cone's base and the yellow one - at the last point in the sample set) so if it bothers you you can remove those.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import numpy as np
from math import pi, cos, sin, sqrt


class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

points = np.array(
[
    [65534,62471,54690],
    [65534,59646,52585],
    [65534,56317,50283],
    [65240,52776,47825],
    [64508,49397,45249],
    [63357,46581,42549],
    [61838,44648,39719],
    [60011,43742,36772],
    [57902,43845,33730],
    [55473,44884,30622],
    [52618,46840,27472],
    [49215,49783,24311],
    [45291,53734,21167],
    [41294,58283,18073],
    [37942,62512,15059],
    [35498,65534,12158],
    [33748,65534,9399],
    [32488,65534,6808],
    [31445,65534,4405],
    [30533,65534,2205]
]
)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('distance')

thetaLevels = np.arange(0, 2*pi + pi/50, pi/50)
cone_height = points[0, 2]
cone_angle = 20.
cone_radius = 0.

cos_cone_angle = cos(cone_angle)
if cos_cone_angle != 0:
    hypotenuse = cone_height/cos_cone_angle
    sin_cone_angle = sin(cone_angle)
    if sin_cone_angle != 0:
        cone_radius = hypotenuse * sin_cone_angle


def pointInsideCircle(x, y, z):
    if cone_radius == 0:
        return False

    # Normalize to scale 0..1
    x = x/65534.
    y = y/65534.
    z = z/65534.

    tip_x = points[0, 0]/65534.
    tip_y = points[0, 1]/65534.

    cone_radius_n = cone_radius/65534.
    cone_height_n = cone_height/65534.

    cone_slice_radius = (cone_radius_n * z)/cone_height_n
    d = cone_slice_radius**2 - (tip_x - x)**2 + (tip_y - y)**2
    d_2 = sqrt((tip_x - x)**2 + (tip_y - y)**2)

    print('''
    point[x=%f, y=%f, z=%f] | slice[x=%f, y=%f, z=%f]\n
    cone(radius=%f, height=%f)\n
    slice(radius=%f)\n
    d = %f\n
    d_2 = %f
    ''' % (x, y, z, tip_x, tip_y, z, cone_radius_n, cone_height_n, cone_slice_radius, d, d_2))

#    if d < 0:
#        return False
    return d_2 <= cone_slice_radius


for x, y, z in points:
    # Slice circumference
    # X,Y of each point lying on the circumference
    sliceCircX = z * np.array([cos(t) for t in thetaLevels]) + points[0, 0]
    sliceCircY = z * np.array([sin(t) for t in thetaLevels]) + points[0, 1]
    ax.plot(sliceCircX,
            sliceCircY,
            -z + points[0, 2],
            'b-')

    # Plot center of cone slice at height of point
    ax.scatter(points[0, 0], points[0, 1], z, s=60, c='k', lw=0)

    valid = pointInsideCircle(x, y, z)
    print('point[%d, %d, %d] %s cone' % (x, y, z, ('inside of/lies on' if valid else 'outside of')))

    # Plot point
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=60, c=('g' if valid else 'r'), lw=0)

    # Point to center of slice
    p2cs = Arrow3D([x, points[0, 0]],
                   [y, points[0, 1]],
                   [z, z],
                   mutation_scale=20,
                   lw=1, arrowstyle='-', color='b', linestyle='dotted')
    ax.add_artist(p2cs)

aStart = Arrow3D([0, points[0, 0]],
                 [0, points[0, 1]],
                 [0, points[0, 2]],
                 mutation_scale=20,
                 lw=3, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
ax.add_artist(aStart)

aEnd = Arrow3D([0, points[-1, 0]],
               [0, points[-1, 1]],
               [0, points[-1, 2]],
               mutation_scale=20,
               lw=3, arrowstyle="-|>", color="y")
ax.add_artist(aEnd)

base = [points[0, 0], points[0, 1], 0]
aBase = Arrow3D([0, base[0]],
                [0, base[1]],
                [0, base[2]],
                mutation_scale=20,
                lw=3, arrowstyle="-|>", color="c")
ax.add_artist(aBase)

tipToBase = [points[0, 0],
             points[0, 1],
             0]
aTipToBase = Arrow3D([points[0, 0], tipToBase[0]],
                     [points[0, 1], tipToBase[1]],
                     [points[0, 2], tipToBase[2]],
                     mutation_scale=20,
                     lw=3, arrowstyle="-|>", color="b")
ax.add_artist(aTipToBase)

fig.show()
input('Press any key to exit')
```

Comment: I haven't done the math, but it seems plausible that some of the red ones might actually be outside and only look like they're inside due to perspective. Can you rotate the visualization?

Comment: This was my first thought but 1)after rotating the plot and looking at it from various perspectives the incorrect points are still incorrect and (most importantly) 2)the points are coloured based on their validity hence it is independent from the perspective but from whether the algorithm marked the points as valid or not. Now that I think about it it's actually independent from the whole plot since the plot is just a fancy way of displaying things.